# how to call computed function in vuejs2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

How to recall computed property. I have some scenario where call to make false and true base on condition but computed is not getting updated. please guide to recall getData();

```
<component
 record="getData"/>

computed: {
    getData(){
        let options = {
            call: true,
            select: true
        }
        return {
            options,
            change: this.change
        }
    }
},
methods: {
    change(){
        this.options.call = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your anwser and share your component ? I believe it would be easier to understand what you ant to do.

Comment: You're doing it the wrong way. this.options belongs to `data`

Comment: ohh yes so how can we update computed value ?

Comment: A computed value is updated whenever one of the data values is changed. If you have to call it manually, it's probably just a method you need.

Comment: change method will not update it ?

Comment: So then is what @EstusFlask, you are doing it the wrong way.  Vue docs says this :"A computed property automatically tracks its reactive dependencies." So as long you are not working with reactive dependencies inside your computed value, it will not update.

Comment: To be even more clear: this.options does not exist in the code you submitted, it would be if it was defined in data

Comment: Let me clear I am pulling options from other component updated question

Answer (score 0):

If you want the computed property to update based on the value of `options.call` changing, then `options` must first be made **reactive** by adding it to your component's [data object](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components#data-Must-Be-a-Function) which you've not yet created.

Once `options` is added to `data` it then becomes part of the component's state, which makes it accessible throughout the rest of the component as `this.options`.  Now your `change()` method will be able to affect it.  Your computed property should be rewritten to return `this.options` instead of creating it's own locally scoped `options`

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      options: {
        call: true,
        select: true
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
      getData() {
          return {
              options: this.options,
              change: this.change
          }
      }
  },
  methods: {
      change(){
          this.options.call = false
      }
  }
}
```

[Vue Playground example](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNp9kj1vgzAQhv+K5SmRIhiyRSTqV4Z2aKu2I4trLsSJsZF9TpEQ/70GA4GqCkLge++1/ZzPNb0vy+jigG5oYrkRJe5SBVWpDZIMDsxJJHWqCMkYssUyjAkxgM6oISJElyi0spurQghnUm4IGgerq2hBAscgD2oTBt2v6bxcF6VDyCbr5YBPM4Tw/AUZnhEIj8JGfTTh6BGPTOXQm0IwtfRgM7QC8KizaaVh3mI5Y5huG7UnQbbkwKSdF+0//k3i8eR9gFCUkiH4iJAkE5ddXffFN00St0KX+XaIWpE7LgU/b1Pa49NdGCRxMHhzEo9r0hVFy7U6iDw6Wa182ztsP90fuZBg3gJzSscKU+rx9c9Lp03a2W4J/PyPfrJVq6X03YAFc/FUYw6Z8dWE9P7zFSo/HpOFzpz07hvJD7BaupYx2B6cyjz2xNfRPhftFRYq/7L7CkHZoajh4oVuptTf/ccbpV9x19F6aBltfgEmbQJN)